# How to fix the errors of npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zsh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuSNl.png)

I am using npm install navigator. But it is showing the errors as shown in the given picture. I am using Mac.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: So is the error there not accurate? Your project has a different name?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're trying to install a package which has the same name as your project. Have you checked the name of the project and did you make sure it is different than the package you're trying to install?

To solve this rename the project name so it differ's from the package you're trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

You have named your project name same as module. 
Try to change the name of project and install the dependency. 
**npm** is understanding as you're installing module in module.